# ether.js ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.decode [ [Getter] ] result

Tags: etherjs

`ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.decode(['address'],'0x08c379a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000124e6f206d61746368696e67206d6574686f640000000000000000000000000000');`

`result == [ [Getter] ]`

`result is error.. how do handle..`

Comment: That data you are passing is way too big to be an abi.encoded address, do you have access the the signature of the function that was called with this data ?

Comment: try{  const a = deocde..   const b = JSON.stringify(a);  // if error data . touch off catch }catch(e){}